# ETag availability guarantees for AWS S3 objects

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Suppose I update an existing AWS S3 object.

```
aws s3 mv dataset.csv s3://my-bucket
```

and then right away, I submit a HEAD request to get the ETag.

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket my-bucket --key dataset.csv
```

Am I guaranteed to get the new up-to-date ETag from HEAD, or is there still a chance AWS is still hashing the object even after `aws s3 mv` completes locally? More generally, where can I read about AWS ETag timing and availability guarantees?

### Edit: custom ETag

As suggested in the comments below, I tried supplying my own ETag using the `--content-md5` flag of `put-object`, but I ran into an error.

```
$ md5sum file
d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e  file
$ aws s3api put-object --bucket my-bucket --key file --body a --content-md5 d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e

An error occurred (InvalidDigest) when calling the PutObject operation: The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid.
```

Comment: The question isn't whether the eTag is updated. It's whether you are accessing the "updated" object. See: [Amazon S3 data consistency model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html)

Comment: So the ETag and data match, but they could both be stale? What would I need to do to guarantee immediate consistency and not just eventual consistency? In PUT, is there a way to set VersionId or Metadata to a UUID that I check locally?

Comment: Yes. And no, consistency model is defined by S3. On a side note, I think you presumed ETag is calculated by S3, but in fact you can put your own ETag. So what you can do is utilize ETag to store your own UUID and in turn use it for checking.

Comment: A custom ETag is even better for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: So then how do I supply an ETag? I tried the `--content-md5` flag but ran into an error (new edit above).

Comment: @landau you can't supply your own custom ETag. `--content-md5` is unrelated to ETag even though they both use MD5. You can supply your own custom user metadata, but I think this is probably a distraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Am I guaranteed to get the new up-to-date ETag from HEAD*

A `HEAD` request would return the new object ETag if the S3 node handling your request already has a version of the bucket index that is fresh enough that it includes the new object.

When you overwrite an object, S3 doesn't literally overwrite anything -- it stores a copy at a new internal location and then changes its internal an index record to point the internal new object location.  The bucket index is replicated and at any instant, each internal index replica lags the primary index by some amount of time, which can be and often is very close to zero, but is not guaranteed to be.

So until the index update has fully propagated, both `GET` and `HEAD` can return either the old or the new object, fully intact, never corrupt and never partially overwritten.

> *is there still a chance AWS is still hashing the object*

Everything is atomic and immutable relative to the body and the metadata (including ETag).  You would never see the new object body with the old ETag.  There is no possible lag time there because S3 actually calculates and returns the new ETag [as part of the upload response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html).

If you absolutely need to receive the new version each time you access an object, you have to upload the object with a new object key.  This is the only immediate consistency guarantee made by S3.  Everything else is eventual; however, ETag and object body won't be out of sync with each other.

Comment: Thanks! One follow-up clarification question: do the same guarantees on the ETag also apply to metadata? After an overwrite, is it possible to have new custom metadata and the old body? Seems like they should be consistent, but I want to be extra sure.

Comment: Yes, they metadata and ETag behave the same way and no, you can't add metadata... however, you can overwrite an object with a copy of itself (avoiding re-upload) and replace the custom metadata with new metadata. (For adding "additional" metadata, you have to supply any of the old metadata that you want to keep.) The copy object operation allows source and target to be the same bucket + object key and that's how metadata "updates" are accomplished.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the ETag and you can't even know what it will be before the upload is finished. The `--content-md5` is to verify the *upload* of the object, but then S3 will calculate the final ETag value ([ref](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-integrity-s3/)).

GET and HEAD requests are read-after-write consistent, so if you create a new object and then get it, you'll always get it right. The docs does not mention ETag specifically, but it's part of the GET, so I suppose it is always up-to-date as well. ([docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel)). One caveat is that this consistency model does not hold in two cases:

- you overwrite the object. In this case you might get the new or the old one
- you issue a HEAD or GET before you upload the object. This shouldn't be a problem usually.